# how to make phpmyadmin work with kohana site? (.htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess, phpmyadmin, kohana

today i was trying to upload phpmyadmin to one of the folders with kohana site, but it turned out that instead of phpmyadmin i get empty page. so i think that this is the problem of rewriting rules in .htaccess in the root directory of the site.

.htaccess file has the following lines:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
<Files .*>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny From All
</Files>
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]
```

my phpmyadmin index.php file is located in phpmyadmin/ directory, but, as i've understood, every request is redirected to index.php in the root directory. how to make phpmyadmin work not breaking routing of kohana?

thanx for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another `RewriteCond` before the last `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/phpmyadmin
```

or to be more explicit, you can add another rule before the existing `RewriteCond`s:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/phpmyadmin
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
```